# CakePHP HABTM deletion

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have `Post HABTM Tags` (tables: `posts`, `tags`, `posts_tags`).

When I delete Post also deleting relations from `post_tags` table - it's okey, but in table `tags` there are still not used tags.

How resolved remove not uset tags?

Comment: Did you set `dependant` in your model relationships?

Comment: There is no option `dependent` for HABTM

Comment: @kicaj Please always mention the exact CakePHP Version you are using!

Comment: I would consider changing this to `hasMany Through` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model

Comment: @ndm: I use the last 2.3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I found the simplest way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1451323/182823:

```
DELETE FROM tags WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM tags_places WHERE tags_places.tag_id = tags.id)
```